# twilio whatsapp sandbox does not automate replies

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

[image: Twilio console error log]

[image: Ngrok dashboard localhost 4040]

[image: Ngrok dashboard]

My Twilio sandbox does not automate replies with my python code, it was working previously, but now it isn't. Same code same method I used before, http request post = 200, no error it just not responds the regular setup with python.

Comment: There could be multiple reasons. Can you describe what you already tried to fix the problem and what you see in the error log of the console?

Comment: i am using whatsapp sandbox, and i can't find any error

Comment: Did you follow a particular tutorial to try this?

Comment: Yes, i did the particular tutorial ,i did everything correctly

Comment: Can you link the tutorial here?

Comment: https://www.twilio.com/blog/build-a-whatsapp-chatbot-with-python-flask-and-twilio

Comment: Can you have a look at the ngrok dashboard at <http://127.0.0.1:4040/> when you try this? Do you see an incoming request when you sent the WA message?

Comment: yes i see, post/bot 200 OK

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of the application log and ngrok dashboard to your question above?

Comment: @IObert i have added the ngrok dashboard screenshot

Comment: Thanks. This screenshot only shows that a request is coming in. Can you open port 4040 on localhost and add these screenshots too? They show what's coming in and how your local app responds.

Comment: @IObert i have added the ngrok localhost port 4040 dashboard

Comment: It seems all right. Can you have a look at the "Message Logs" and "Error Logs" which are both described here: <https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/debugging-tools>

Do you see your incoming messages here? Possibly also with an error description.

Comment: @IObert i have added a screenshot of the errors i found on my error log dashboard

Comment: Based on the screenshot. I would say you return invalid TwiML and therefore the response cannot be processed (it seems like an <html> tag is causing the problem). Are you sure you didn't edit the code since the last time it worked?